# Read password protected PDF in Pentaho using UDJC

Tags: itext, pentaho, pdf-reader, pdfstamper

I am trying to unlock the password protected PDF using **bcprov-jdk15on-1.56.jar** and **itextpdf-5.5.10.jar** but I am getting following exception. I am using 'User Defined Java Class' task of transformation.

Exception: **class "org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1Primitive"'s signer information does not match signer information of other classes in the same package**

Here is the lines of code I wrote,

```
String pdfFilePath = get(Fields.In, "PDFFilePath").getString(r);

String dest = pdfFilePath +"_unlocked.pdf";

try {
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdfFilePath,owner_password.getBytes());
    PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(dest));

    stamper.close();
    reader.close();
}
catch(Exception e) {
    logBasic("EXCEPTION WHILE UNLOCKING PDF = " + e.getMessage());
}
```

Any idea, what's wrong with this?

Thanks,
Nilesh

Comment: You mention Pentaho. Are you saying Pentaho ships with the AGPL'ed iText 5.5.10? If so, is Pentaho releasing its code as AGPL?

Comment: @BrunoLowagie, not clear which is the licensing, but the sources are indeed released: https://github.com/pentaho

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you have multiple BouncyCastle jars in your classpath. Try using version `1.49` which is the version iText `5.5.10` is compiled against and if it does not help, you will have to figure out which jars happen to be in your classpath and get rid of the duplicates.

Comment: Running `mvn dependency:tree` might help there.

Comment: @Alexey-  Thanks. There was already a bcprov-jdk14-138.jar which comes default with Pentaho (along with all other libraries). Deleted it and not getting the above error. But now I am running into other issue. It's not able to open the PDF file with that password. Password is correct; I can open PDF with same password from Acrobat reader.   I get error "PdfReader not opened with owner password" from Pentaho UDJC task.

Comment: @NNaseet, this might be more of a question to the developers of `Pentaho`, on whether they use `iText` correctly. However, the problem can be much simpler: pdf documents may have user and owner passwords, and only owner passwords allow full control over documents. The password you provide is most likely a user password which is enough to read the document, but not enough to do the manipulations that are tried to be done.

Comment: @AlexeySubach - yes, it is owner password only. Yeah, I am checking with Pentaho community. Thanks for your help !

Comment: @AlexeySubach - Looks like that is user password, because same program worked for other PDF with owner password.